# Keras vertical ensemble model with condition in between

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, ensemble-learning

I have trained two separate models

- ModelA: Checks if the input text is related to my work (Binary Classifier [related/not-related])
- ModelB: Classifier of related texts (Classifier [good/normal/bad]). Only the related texts are relayed to this model from ModelA

I want

- ModelC: Ensemble classifier that outputs [good/normal/bad/not-related]
- I'll be training in batches. And there can be mix of `not-related` and `good/normal/bad` in one batch. I need them separated.

Some pseudo code of what i need

```
# Output of modelA will be a vector I presume `(1, None)` where `None` is batch
def ModelC.predict(input):
    outputA = ModelA(input)
    if outputA == 'not-related':
        return outputA
    return ModelB(outputA)
```

I don't know how to include the `if` logic inside the models inference. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define your own model. I'm surprised your other models are outputting strings instead of numbers, but without more info this is about all I can give you, so I will assume the output of model A is a string.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class ModelC(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, A, B):
    super(ModelC, self).__init__()
    self.A = A
    self.B = B

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    x = self.A(inputs, training)
    if x == 'not-related':
        return x
    return self.B(inputs, training)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Plus sorry for not making my question more specific. I have one more requirement. How will this work if I'm training in batches? I don't know how to " within a batch `if x == 'not-related': return x else return self.B(inputs, training)`

Comment: This method would not work for batch training. Since some inputs may need to use B and others may need to use A, it would not be possible to return early. In that case you would be better off 1) having the output related/not-related be a 0-1 value and  2) multiply the layer A with the B layer.

Comment: If you wanted to modify the above example to work with strings, I think it could be made to work using `tf.where` https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where. You won't save computation by returning early, but it should get the job done. `where(cond, x, y)` gives you a tensor of elements from x where cond is true and elements from y where cond is false. So take x to be the output of A, and y to be the output of B, and cond to be `tf.equal(x, 'not-related') `

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try what you suggested and I will edit your answer with my resulting code. Thanks again